# Transfer function from a block diagram

Tags: transfer-function

Today I was asked a question in control lecture.

There are extra questions about this block diagram but I need to find;

- the transfer function of this foreforward block diagram and find the roots
- the state functions of this system

I am a bit newbie at block diagrams but not too bad.

I have found some examples at internet, but could not find.
I followed the diagram: "X2= (U-X1)*1/(s+1)" and "X1 = U*(1/s+2)".

Therefore I found **Y/U = (1-1/(s+2))*(1/(s+1))**.
then >>> Y/U= (s+1)/(s^2+3s+2).

and

*the roots of the system are s1 = -2 and s2= -1*

But this answer was wrong as assistant said. I could not understand why!

[image]

Thank you for helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{Y}{U} = \frac{(s+1)}{s^2+3s+2} = \frac{\color{red}{(s+1)}}{(s+2)\color{red}{(s+1)}} = \frac{1}{(s+2)}
$$

This **may** be why the assistant said you were wrong.

Comment: But the answer was 1/( s*(s+1)) and I could not understand how.

Comment: I too cannot imagine how they arrived at that answer. Perhaps there is more context to this question which you have not provided in the above question? I guess you can ask the (teaching?) assistant to explain it step by step (or ask the professor).